# Can water seep in?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-technique

Today morning I was sweating a lot, and a drop of it directly fell on my iPhone's home button.

Considering the height of fall to be approx. $30 cm$, I started wondering whether water could seep in.

Probably surface tension must have blocked water from entering the iPhone (since the difference in the radius of home button and the circular home button slot on the glass ~ $0.1mm$ or so).

Now,
What this incident made me think is a mathematical model of this.

I don't know where to start from.

Suppose I consider the temperature to be $30^{o}C$ and find the average velocity of the gas molecules: ${(3RT/M)^{1/2}}$ above the liquid on my home button, find the momentum transferred per second (assuming the average molar mass of air = $M = 29 g/mol$), assume the glass-water contact angle to be $5^{o}$ and find the surface area (by assuming it to be part of a sphere, and also by assuming the initial volume of water to $2.5 ml$) since the radius of button is $0.6cm$ I can find the vertical component force due to surface tension ( = $2 \pi (0.006) T$ ) and obviously $mg= (4/3) \pi [(\frac{2.5 \cdot 1000}{(4/3) \pi})^{(1/3)}]^3 (1) (9.8) $ ), what else am I missing?

Will neglecting friction really affect?

Basically if I have an opening of width $d$, what should be the minimum height from where I should drop a water droplet such the maximum amount passes through the opening?

Comment: Read about [capillary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action).